# How to search parents?

Tags: wpf, parent

I have construction:

```
Grid a = ((((usercontrol.Parent as DockPanel).Parent as ScrollViewer).Parent as Grid)
```

Is it possible to find a tree or a parent element?

example: Grid a = GetFirstParent(usercontrol,"Grid")  Grid - is Type element

Comment: Just a note on your design there. the "as" operator will return null if it is unable to convert. Making this particular function extremely reliant on the visual structure of your user control. If you change it, this will probably throw null exceptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Grid a = userControl.FindParent<Grid>();
```

---

```
    public static T FindParent<T>(this DependencyObject startElement)
        where T : DependencyObject
    {
        DependencyObject parent = GetParentObject(startElement);
        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        T typedParent = parent as T;
        if (typedParent != null)
        {
            return typedParent;
        }

        return FindParent<T>(parent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx) class.

It has a method, GetParent, that returns the parent of a control (a DependencyObject really).